# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate profiler throwing exception

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

when we profile our EXE throught Visual Studio 2010 profiler it throw up message at the end and no any performance report are generating.

```
  Profiling started.
    Profiling process ID 21860 (M3 Shell).
    Process ID 21860 has exited.
    Data written to M:\Documents and Settings\Sunil.Naudiyal\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\M3 Shell131118.vsp.
    Profiling finished.
    PRF0025: No data was collected.
    Profiling complete.
```

Step Which i follow

```
Go to tab Analyze>>Lunch Performance Wizard>>CPU Sampling>>Next>>An Executable file(.exe)>>Next>select path to the executable file>>Finish
```

Comment: How long did the program run?  If this took less than a few seconds then it just quit too soon.  If that was intentional then you need to switch to instrumenting mode.

Answer (score 0):

this is Andre from the Visual Studio profiler team. What OS are you on? Sampling collects period stacks at a particular frequency. It is possible that you application runs so fast that by the time VisualStudio attaches, your process has already died. If this is the case then instrumentation may be a better solution (however instrumentation has a high overhead and has been known to generate gigabytes of data in only a few seconds). Let me know if you need help in using instrumentation

Comment: its ms windows server 2003R2.actually.i want to fetch code of Exe when its running using .net profiler.its possible ?.when i was trying this it giving me above exception message.